# Ubuntu dependency problems

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, dependencies

My ubuntu 12.4 box has been off for 10 days. Upon returning to it I have found that there's no sound and steam games (for linux) won't start.

There is a dependancy problem. I'm guessing is causing the sound & graphics problems. I can't update all my packages because aptitude keeps telling me that dpkg has errors. It appears to be to do with some dependancies being out of date. Here is some of the most informative bits from the masses of reports spewed by apt-get and aptitude:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 apache2-mpm-prefork : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5) but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.6 is installed
 apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.5) but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.6 is installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12 is installed
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.2)


Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
 udev
 bluez
 cups
 network-manager
 apache2.2-common
 apache2-mpm-prefork
 apache2
 libsolid4
 libkio5
 kdoctools
 kdelibs-bin
 libkparts4
 libkde3support4
 libkdewebkit5
 libkemoticons4
 libkfile4
 libktexteditor4
 libkhtml5
 kdelibs5-plugins
 libapache2-mod-php5
 libkmediaplayer4
 libknewstuff3-4
 libknotifyconfig4
 libkprintutils4
 libplasma3
 openssh-server
 ssh
```

This is what I tried so far (based on googleing):

```
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get --fix-broken install
aptitude upgrade
```

aptitude upgrade says this:
http://pastebin.com/MJuLn9GY

My /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe
```

How can I fix this dependency issue?

Also: This has happened before after I returned from a holiday. How can I prevent this form happening again?

Comment: reinstalling apache, then "sudo mv /etc/init/procps.conf /etc/init/procps.conf.old;" made "sudo aptitude install procps" work. Sound is no better.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else also runs into a similar problem:

One option is to use dpkg and where necessary force the installation / configuration of certain packages. I came to this question because of the mentioning of openssh-server, which in my case was stuck.

> openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.2)

It was stuck because openssh-client was already updated (somehow) to 1.4.
I managed to solve this by force the configuration of the openssh-server by using

> $> dpkg --force-depends-version --configure openssh-server

which installed the openssh-server, which then allowed me to update the openssh-server to a newer version corresponding with the installed openssh-client version.